# Use selected radio button in another function

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, matlab-guide

I have  GUI created with GUIDE. I have 3 radiobuttons in a group. When I run the program and after I enter in values for some calculations I get plots for pressure, temperature, lift/drag force (dependent on which radiobutton I push). The structure of program is as follows:

Main code (GUI):
passes values to a function named Apollo after the "Calculate" button is pushed.

Apollo code:
contains sub functions to calculate necessary values for the calculation of the pressure, temperature, and lift/drag force. Last sub function is called plot_data. This function plots the shape of the space craft in one figure and plots the pressure, temperature, lift/drag force in another figure upon selection of the corresponding radiobutton.

Problem - I'm new at programming a GUI. I'm having problems figuring out how to determine which radiobutton is selected from the GUI and using some sort of logic as a switch in my plot_data function. I would like for the select case to be in the plot_data function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your radiobutton handles are `rb1` and `rb2` and they are stored in `handles` structure. Then, you can check if they are selected using the `'Value'` property.

```
function apollo(hObj, eventdata, handles)
    if get(handles.hrb1, 'Value')
        % do stuff
    elseif get(handles.hrb2, 'Value')
        % do other stuff
    end
end
```

---

**Update:** Response to OP's comment about `SelectionChangeFcn`:

If you do not have a lot of data you can plot them all at the beginning and then change the `Visible` properties of the plots.

```
function cbSelectionChange(hObj, eventdata, handles)
    rbTag = get(eventData.NewValue, 'Tag');
    switch rbTag
        case 'rb1'
            set(handles.plotHandle1, 'Visible', 'On');
            set(handles.plotHandle2, 'Visible', 'Off');
        case 'rb2'
            set(handles.plotHandle2, 'Visible', 'On');
            set(handles.plotHandle1, 'Visible', 'Off');
    end
end
```

If you do have a lot data you can call plot_data function from `SelectionChangeFcn` callback.

```
function cbSelectionChange(hObj, eventdata, handles)
    rbTag = get(eventData.NewValue, 'Tag');
    switch rbTag
        case 'rb1'
            plot_data(yourArguments1);
        case 'rb2'
            plot_data(yourArguments2);
    end
end
```

Performance of your code will not be affected by passing the data unless you modify it. Doug Hull says [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152):

> MATLAB uses a system commonly called "copy-on-write" to avoid making a
>   copy of the input argument inside the function workspace until or
>   unless you modify the input argument. If you do not modify the input
>   argument, MATLAB will avoid making a copy.

Comment: Thanks HebeleHododo, that worked perfectly. But now upon running the program, I realized that I didn't set it up correctly. What I need to do now is to change the code so that whenever I click on a radio button, it will change to the appropriate plot instead of me clicking on the calculate button all the time. I know that this will probably involve using a SelectionChangeFnc callback for the radiobutton group. I don't really want to pass the data sets from plot_data.m through Apollo.m into the main GUI. Is there a way to just plot all the plots and then turn them on or off from the main GUI?

Comment: @roldy I updated my answer. I guess changing the `Visible` property was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to do something after user clicks on a radiobutton, you should edit "callback" property of your object.
- If you want to test the state of radiobutton from your code, your should check "Value" property. It would be one for selected button and zero otherwise.
- Look through [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCFGtUvRX6w) tutorial